# How to delay beans until all spring cloud connectors scan is finished?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I need to delay my application "service" bean processing after all Spring Boot cloud auto-configuration is finished.

"service" bean has dependency both on SQL `DataSource` and other `Bean` (S3 repository) which is optional and can be created based on cloud services configuration or directly configured properties (or even not created at all). Both underlying S3 and SQL services are configured perfectly based on various external conditions. They behave well with direct, inderect properties, cloud and so on.

So now I have something like...

```
@Autowired(required=false)
S3Storage s3;

@Autowired
SQLDatabase db;

@Bean
MyService myservice() {
  if (s3 != null) {
    return new SQLWithS3Implementation(db, s3);
  } else {
    return new SQLImplementation(db);
  }
}
```

What have I do with this `Bean` so it is not processed before `cloud` services (`spring-cloud-connectors` is used) with s3 yet null?

- I cannot make s3 required. It is not always configured.
- I cannot use @Lazy. References from other services... will be messy at least (if possible).

I need something like...

```
@ProcessAfter(CloudAutoConfiguration.class)
```

But how actually to do so in `Spring Boot` / `Spring Cloud`?

Comment: So, you can not do this with `@DependsOn("beanB")` annotation, right?

Comment: Yes, @DependsOn has problem that S3 is optional. And as I can see it is checked in any case too early (properties are not yet supported by cloud)..

Comment: Will not `MyService myservice(S3Storage s3) { ... }` work for you?

Comment: No, in this case @Autowire even does not account 'required' = false.

Comment: in case of spring boot you can make use of @ConditionalOnBean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this special case nothing was able to help me but 'reverse of the ownership'.

I have changed the result of `@Bean` on cloud service scan. Now it creates not storage service info but repository created with these properties.

```
@ServiceScan
public class S3CloudCOnfig extends AbstractCloudConfig {

    @Autowired
    @Bean
    public S3Repository s3Repository(final MyService service) {

        // Cloud service configuration.
        S3Properties properties = null;
        try {
        } catch (...) {
            // No service is configured...
        }

        S3Repository result = null;
        if (properties) {
            result = new S3Repository(properties);
            service.setObjectStorage(service);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

As `service` is 100% configured just through normal configurations optional `S3Repository` than registers on service. This solves problem of S3 repository being optional.

And `service` logics just accounts optional strategy on S3 repository being available. So no any `@Autowired(required = false)`.

Answer (score 1):

In Spring boot, you can make use of **@ConditionalOnBean**
Doc : http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnBean.html

```
   @ConditionalOnBean(CloudAutoConfiguration.class)
```

Comment: No, this has no effect on sequence. Just 'if' condition which does not help.

Comment: Can you do DependsOn for order?